# Access pk from related model using prefetch and to_attr

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following model relationship:

```
class CustomEmail(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(SystemEmail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In a `ListView`, I am displaying `SystemEmail` objects, obtained by:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    prefetch = Prefetch('customemail_set', 
                        queryset=CustomEmail.objects.filter(client=self.request.user.client),
                        to_attr='custom_email')
    return (SystemEmail.objects.filter(user_editable=True)
            .order_by('template_name').prefetch_related(prefetch))
```

Now, in my template, I am attempting to access the `pk` from the related `CustomEmail` through the `to_att` like so:

```
{% for email in system_emails %}
    {% if email.custom_email %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'settings:edit_custom_email' email.custom_email.pk %}">Edit</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The part where I call `email.custom_email.pk` doesn't retrun anything. How can I (if at all possible) get the `pk` using the `to_attr` from the related `CustomEmail`?

**EDIT**

I ommitted to mention that in my application, I will only have a single `CustomEmail` for each `SystemEmail` for each client (see the `Prefetch` queryset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman pointed out, `email.custom_email` is a list. So in order for me to get the `pk`, I needed to do the following:

```
email.custom_email.0.pk
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you expect that to work. `prefetch_related` is for the many side of a relationship - you have a queryset of items for each email. Just because you attached it to `custom_email` rather than `customemail_set` doesn't mean there is suddenly a single item; there are still many, and `email.custom_email` is a *list* of CustomEmail objects.

So you probably need to iterate through the list:

```
{% for custom_email in email.custom_email.all %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'settings:edit_custom_email' custom_email.pk %}">Edit</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per my edit, there will only be one `CustomEmail` for each `SystemEmail` for each client. But you did mention in your answer that `email.custom_email` is a list (which I overlooked), and so if I use `email.custom_email.0.pk` I get the desired result. However, based on your answer, perhaps there is a better way. Do you have any other suggestions on a better approach?

Comment: One option might be to start from CustomEmail rather than SystemEmail, then you can use `select_related` and access the systememail fields from there.